# Combining averages of two lists

Tags: python, list, average

Suppose I have the function:

```
def avg_grams(l: list) -> float:
    ''' Returns the average grams of parameter list
    '''
    result = 0
    for x in C:
        result += float(x.calories)
    return result / len(l)
```

The function is supposed to return the average grams within a given list of grams. However, if I have two lists, how do I use this function to find the overall average of both lists?

For example:

```
List A: [2, 3, 4] - Average: 3
List B: [3, 4, 5] - Average: 4
Overall avg: 3.5
```

Comment: `avg_grams(A + B)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

### A)

```
def avg_grams(lists):
    """Returns the average grams of parameter list """
    sums = [sum(l) / float(len(l)) for l in lists]
    overall_sum = sum(sums) / float(len(sums))
    return sums, overall_sum

a = [2, 3, 4]
b = [3, 4, 5]

print('Sums: {} \noverall sum: {}'.format(*avg_grams((a, b))))
```

Out:

```
Sums: [3.0, 4.0] 
overall sum: 3.5
```

#### B)

Or if you are not interested in the individual sums, try this one:

```
def avg_grams(some_list):
    """ Returns the average grams of parameter list """
    return sum(some_list) / float(len(some_list))

a = [2, 3, 4]
b = [3, 4, 5]

print('overall sum: {}'.format(avg_grams(a+b)))
```

Out:

```
overall sum: 3.5
```

#### Note:

A and B can produce different results depending on whether the lists have different lengths or not; it really depends what you want to accomplish, the weighted mean, or the mean of all items (from all the lists) combined

Answer (score 0):

You can write `avg_grams(A+B)`, though this may not have desired results if `A` and `B` are different lengths.

PS Your variable names need some cleaning up, for example you are using `C` which is not defined anywhere, and you are looking for `x.calories` while your example uses a simple list of integers.

Comment: What does different length of the lists have to do with calculating their average? Also clarify what you mean by `avg_grams(A + B)`